# Chrome crops padding and border when float

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, crop

https://jsfiddle.net/x1vqv7ju/

```
<div style='float:right;padding:10px;border:1px solid black;'>
<a style='padding:10px;border:1px solid black' href='#'><img style='width:16px' src='http://google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png' /></a><a style='padding:10px;border:1px solid black' href='#'><img style='width:16px' src='http://google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png' /></a>
</div>
```

How it should be (Firefox, also tested in ie):
[image]

How Chrome do it:
[image]

Chrome just crops it.
What is going on here? Is it a bug, or some future? Who is right here, Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/x1vqv7ju/1/ ? Now padding is really shown (in chrome and firefox)

Comment: There are definitely many kludges to change this. Also, you can just and `&nbsp;` after second `img`: https://jsfiddle.net/wL1c0p06/ , I will use yours, it is more clean.